# I can not apply css on. hbs file in express js

Tags: node.js, express

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/ '  because it's MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

I can give also absolute path but dont apply css on. hbs file I also use app. Get method for render the. hbs file